# TypeScript map function to change property type

Tags: typescript

I am trying to use map function to transform property type.

```
class A {... }
class B {... }

var var1 = [{path:"aa",comp:"A"},{path:"b",comp:"B"}];
var var2 = var1.map(function(obj){ 
   var rObj = {path: obj.path, component: A};
   return rObj;
});
```

The above code will return to var2

```
[{path:"aa",comp:A},{path:"b",comp:A}]
```

What I need is

```
[{path:"aa",comp:A},{path:"b",comp:B}]
```

How can I achieve this purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to map between a class name (as string) to the actual class.
You can just maintain a mapping object like so:

```
class A { ... }
class B { ... }

var nameToClassMapping = {
    A: A,
    B: B
};

var var1 = [{ path: "aa", comp: "A" }, { path: "b", comp: "B" }];
var var2 = var1.map(function(obj) { 
    var rObj = { path: obj.path, component: nameToClassMapping[obj.comp] };
    return rObj;
});
```

[Code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20A%20%7B%20%7D%0Aclass%20B%20%7B%20%7D%0A%0Avar%20nameToClassMapping%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20A%3A%20A%2C%0A%20%20%20%20B%3A%20B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Avar%20var1%20%3D%20%5B%7B%20path%3A%20%22aa%22%2C%20comp%3A%20%22A%22%20%7D%2C%20%7B%20path%3A%20%22b%22%2C%20comp%3A%20%22B%22%20%7D%5D%3B%0Avar%20var2%20%3D%20var1.map(function(obj)%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20var%20rObj%20%3D%20%7B%20path%3A%20obj.path%2C%20component%3A%20nameToClassMapping%5Bobj.comp%5D%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20rObj%3B%0A%7D)%3B)

Comment: I ran the code and it returned the expected result. Check the link to playground in my answer (just added it)

Comment: If class A and B is define in the same file it works as expected. But if the class is an imported one using import {A,B} from ... then the component property showed undefined. Why is so?

Comment: are you sure that the classes were loaded? if you do `console.log(A, B)` after the `import` what do you get?

Comment: My bad. I mismatched property name and type in nameToClassMapping . Thanks you so much for your patience with me. It works great.