# TypeScript dynamically generate string name to class mapping object

Tags: typescript

This is a follow up question for [TypeScript map function to change property type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37227739/typescript-map-function-to-change-property-type/37227878?noredirect=1#comment61992062_37227878).

If I have the following

```
class A {  }
class B {  }
var var1 = [{ path: "aa", comp: "A" }, { path: "b", comp: "B" }];
```

Is there a way to programmatically generate a mapping object like this

```
var nameToClassMapping = {
    A: A,
    B: B
};
```

rather than hardcode it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [a decorator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html) to do that:

```
var nameToClassMapping = {};

function myDecorator(target: any) {
    nameToClassMapping[target.name] = target;
}

@myDecorator
class A { }
```

I haven't tested it, but it should work, or at least give you a way.

Comment: so the @myDecorator is used each class A and B? what is the scope if nameToClassMapping? Can you explain a bit? Thanks,

Comment: Yes, you need to use this decorator before every class you want to be able to map to. The decorator is just a function that is executed and it receives the class after it as parameter. The link in my question to the official documentation is a good place to start.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.